# How do I access the extra/special video settings'?

Tags: caster

The tutorial for *[Caster](http://www.elecorn.com/caster3d/)* specifically mentions editing a certain game file (settings.ini) in order to access video settings that aren't available from the in-game menu, like shadows, anti aliasing, etc.  However, when I change all of the values of '0' for these things in the file to '1', the game simply resets them all to 0, and nothing is changed.

How can I edit this file without the game overwriting it?  Is this only a problem with the Steam version of the game (which I am playing)?

In addition, what are the values I need to use to activate the effects?

Comment: Have you tried editing the file while the game is not running?

Comment: @wok yes.  As soon as I start it again, it resets the values.

Comment: Does setting it read-only not work? (Odd that it has this problem in the first place though, since the game itself advises editing it…)

Comment: ...Strange, it doesn't seem to be resetting it now, but none of my changes appear to have made any difference.  Now I guess I just need to know the correct values.